# How do I call a second code with a loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA beginner and I there is clearly something wrong with my code. I get the

> error 1004 - Run Time Error

when the code goes through `cells(i,1).value= formatcell`

Please kindly advice?
Thank you

```
Sub firstcode()
Dim formatcell As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
formatcell = Cells(1, 1).Value
For i = 0 To lastrow

If formatcell < 20 Then

Call SecondCode(True, "Arial", 22)
Else
Call SecondCode(False, "Times", 30)

End If

Cells(i, 1).Value = formatcell
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub SecondCode(BoldValue As Boolean, NameValue As String, SizeValue)
With ActiveCell.Font
.Bold = BoldValue
.name = NameValue
.Size = SizeValue
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot have `i` set to `0` in your loop as `Cells(i, 1).value` is then an invalid reference i.e. `Cells(0, 1).value`. No such cells exists.

Comment: @AlexP  Ha! thank you!  that makes sense:-) I changed it to 1 to lastrow but now cell 1,1 repeats it self. If I have a 2 in A1 it loops as 2 into the entire column A. Please help

Comment: That's how your code is set up! `Cells(i, 1).Value = formatcell` sets each cell to the value `formatcell`. What outcome do you want?

Comment: @AlexP haha ok no thats not what I want! if I have a different number in each cell in column a, 30, 5, 2 ect I want to change the font ect for each of them depending on the number. I do not wish to have 30 repeat itself ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler version?

```
Sub FormatCells()
    Dim formatcell As Range, lastRow As Long, cl As Range

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set formatcell = Range("A1")

    For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If formatcell < 20 Then
            cl.Font.Bold = True
            cl.Font.Name = "Arial"
            cl.Font.Size = 22
        Else
            cl.Font.Bold = False
            cl.Font.Name = "Times"
            cl.Font.Size = 30
        End If

        cl.Value = formatcell
    Next cl
End Sub
```

**Revised code**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim switchVal As Range, lastRow As Long, cl As Range

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set switchVal = Range("A1")

    For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If cl < switchVal Then
            FormatCell cl, True, "Arial", 22
        Else
            FormatCell cl, False, "Times", 30
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub

Sub FormatCell(cl As Range, bold As Boolean, font As String, size As Integer)
    cl.font.bold = bold
    cl.font.Name = font
    cl.font.size = size
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats excellent too Alex!! I need all help I can get :) You taught me another way to loop! But as I am new to VBA I really want to understand how I use loop and call a second code too..

Comment: See `Revised Code`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!! I am afraid I get an error   FormatCell True, "Arial", 22  that it is an incorrect property (poor translation my excel is in French)

Comment: I still get the same error when the code reaches FormatCell True, "Arial", 22 when I copy your revised version

Comment: Sorry again. Just updated the code. It works now - I tested on my machine.

Comment: Excellent!!! That's super cool. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code below to avoid the many pitfalls you will run into if you keep what you have. I left overall structure the same, but made it cleaner and commented why I changed what I changed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub firstcode()

    Dim formatcell As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'always declare and work with parent object (otherwise Cells may refer to a worksheet you don't expect it to
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

    With ws

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        formatcell = .Cells(1, 1).Value

        Dim i as Long
        For i = 1 To lastrow 'there is no row 0 in excel so start with 1

            Select Case formatcell < 20 'select case easier to read for me
                Case True: SecondCode .Cells(i, 1), True, "Arial", 22 'writing call is not needed
                Case False: SecondCode .Cells(i, 1), True, "Times", 30
            End Select

            .Cells(i, 1).Value = formatcell

        Next i

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SecondCode(rng As Range, BoldValue As Boolean, NameValue As String, SizeValue As Integer)

    'again work directly with the object. using `ActiveCell can cause undesireable errors
    With rng.Font
        .Bold = BoldValue
        .Name = NameValue
        .Size = SizeValue
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott but I get an error that variable is not defined. I changed Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6) but I can not even go step by step to debug as soon as I run I get an error

Comment: Very useful and helpful comments Scott. I learnt a lot of things. Will definitely set my worksheet and avoid using activecell.

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the loop i gets highlighted when I attempt to run the code and then I get the error but I am not able to pass line by line with the yellow marker

Comment: @christinelly - try now. I did not declare variable `i`. I have edited my answer to declare this

Comment: It gets stuck at Next i it says error next without For

Comment: @christinelly - sorry. I fixed it. forgot `Select` in `End Select`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re after this

```
Sub firstcode()
    Dim formatcell As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With WorkSheets("mySheetName") ‘ change mySheetName to your actual sheet name
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            formatcell = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            If formatcell < 20 Then
                SecondCode  .Cells(i, 1), True, "Arial", 22
            Else
                SecondCode  .Cells(i, 1), False, "Times", 30
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SecondCode(cell As Range, BoldValue As Boolean, NameValue As String, SizeValue)
    With cell.Font
        .Bold = BoldValue
        .name = NameValue
        .Size = SizeValue
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! But I get an error 13 at line    formatcell = .Cells(i, 1).Value , any idea what is going on?